# How to customise CupertinoTabBar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-cupertino

It's a vague one but can we customize `CupertinoTabBar` and make it look like this - 
[image: This bottomNarBar is made using CurvedNavBar package from pub.dev]

Comment: It can be done by code, but usually most of the time people use rive.app to build the animation and then use it on flutter as a FlareActor with flare_flutter package

Comment: I can't use rive.app. Need to do it using code. You have any idea how to do it using code?